# calculate the accumulative in php

Tags: php, string

Below given is my code in which i am trying to do is get the in_time and out time of employees basically i am building an attendance system in which system is going to keep an account of employee timings i.e when he was present in office and when he was not...Below is my mysql table from which i am fetching the in and out time of employee from the table below you can clearly see that there were two sessions of that specific employee on the respective date 
1)starting from 11:00:00 and ending at 13:00:00
2)starting from 14:00:00 abd ending at 17:00:00

now you can see from the code that i am creating an array of in_time and out_time 
here is the tricky path...
now i want to add the total time of the 1st session i.e 11:00:00+13:00:00 and same is for the second session then i want to add both the timings of 1st session and 2nd session...
i tried using strntotime fuction but since my in and out times are in array therefore it dint work for me
SO KINDLY HELP ME ACHIEVE this and help me inculcate sense in my mind that how to achieve this ...

[image]

```
///get employee timings w.r.t to date
$sql="SELECT * from employee_timings where emp_timing_date='$date'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$array_in_time=array();
$array_out_time=array();
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    # code...
     array_push($array_in_time, $result['emp_in_time']);
     array_push($array_out_time,$result['emp_out_time']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following modifications to your while loop

```
$emp_accumulated_time = array();

while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  # calculate time interval for each session
  $time_interval = strtotime($result['emp_out_time']) - strtotime($result['emp_in_time']);

  # accumulated session time for each employee
  $emp_accumulated_time[$query['emp_timing_employee_id']] += time_interval;
}
```

And now you can retrieve the accumulated session time for empoyee using `$emp_accumulated_time[$employee_id]`

Comment: sir i dint get anything you did

Comment: @json i tried echoing $time_interval and the result was 720010800 what was that

Comment: It's supposed to be unix timestamp. By substracting two unix timestamps, you get the time difference (in seconds). But the number you are getting seems a little off. What are the values of `strtotime($result['emp_out_time'])` and `strtotime($result['emp_int_time'])` ?